Ruffle loading from a path, how do I load from a file input button?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>emu</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ruffle-rs/ruffle"></script>
<div id="gameWin"></div>
<input type="file" id="flash" accept="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<button onclick="runSWF()">Click to load the SWF!</button>
<script>
function runSWF() {
// flash emu load
var ruf = window.RufflePlayer.newest();
var plr = ruf.createPlayer();
var cont = document.querySelector("#gameWin");
cont.appendChild(plr);

var file = document.querySelector("#flash")
if (file && file.files[0]) {

plr.load(INPUT FILE NOT FILE PATH); // basically load the file input's file instead of a preset file from a path
} else {
alert("You forgot to input your SWF!!")
}
}
</script>
</html>

Issue explained in comment, load the file DIRECTLY for ruffle instead of a file path, basically to load a file through an <input type="file">, so you can basically load any SWF file that you can grab, instead of loading a preset amount of them, via a directory.
Sorry if this is a poor explanation, I'm not that good with this stuff.

the google chrome FileSystemAccess API might be useful to you

You are immediately testing if a file is loaded the second the program runs, so the user would never be able to upload a file on time.  You need to add an listener for when the user uploads a file, and then load the player with the file.
var file = document.querySelector("#flash")
file.onchange = () => {
    if (file && file.files[0]) {
         plr.load(URL.createObjectURL(file.files[0])); 
    } else {
         alert("You forgot to input your SWF!!")
    }
}


Technically speaking, the .onchange had to be removed. The file.onchange fires before the button is pressed, as you input the swf then click the silly lil button  to run function runSWF(), giving it enough time to load. However, you have solved my issue, as URL.createObjectUrl has solved my issue. Thank you for spending your time on this, I really appreciate it.

No problem, I'm glad I could help
